# CSS Sidebar Menu not showing Child items in Mobile view

Tags: css, menu, menuitem

The Sidebar Menu looks completely fine when viewing on a computer/laptop screen and also a tablet/iPad, but for some reason it is not showing **Child** items of the Menu in **Mobile** view.

[View Link Here](http://test.snowflakesoftware.com/markets/aviation/)

I've tried adding things from the Menu to the CSS Mobile version under theme.css but it still doesn't show the Child items. I have no idea why it isn't working? It's baffling me!

Don't suppose anybody could lend another pair of eyes to see if there is something I have missed? I would really appreciate it!

Below is the current CSS for the Mobile view:

```
#widget_nav_menu li {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    list-style: none; 
    text-align: center;
    width: 313px;
    /* padding: 5px;
     margin: 5px;*/
    background: #f4f8fa;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c3ced5;
    height: 34px;
    text-indent: none;
    color: #174267;
}

#widget_nav_menu a {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #174267;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 11px 0 15px 7px;
}

#widget_nav_menu a.active,
#widget_nav_menu a:hover {
    background-image: url(images/hover_bg.png);
    background-position: right -5px;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    /*z-index: 10;*/
    color: #fff;
    /*margin-right: -17px;*/
}

#widget_nav_menu li.current_page_item a {
    background-image: url("images/hover_bg_small.png");
    background-position: right -5px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 11px 0;
    width: 318px;
}

#widget_nav_menu li a:hover {
    background-image: url("images/hover_bg_small.png");
    background-position: right -5px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 11px 0;
    width: 318px; 
}

#widget_nav_menu a:hover li {
}

#widget_nav_menu .sub-menu {
    /* margin-left:10px; */
}

        #widget_nav_menu li ul {
            position: absolute;
            width: 318px
            left: -999em;
        }
        #widget_nav_menu li:hover ul {
            left: auto;
        }

        #widget_nav_menu li:hover ul, #widget_nav_menu li.sfhover ul {
            left: auto;
        }

            /*** Multi Level ***/
            #widget_nav_menu li ul ul {
                margin: -1em 0 0 10em;
            }

            #widget_nav_menu li:hover ul ul, #widget_nav_menu li.sfhover ul ul {
                left: -999em;
            }

        #widget_nav_menu li ul li.current_page_item a:hover {
            width: 318px;
            background-image: url("images/hover_bg_small.png");
            background-position: right -5px;
            color: #fff;
            margin-right: -17px;
        }

.menu-sectors-container li {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    width: 318px;
    background: #f4f8fa;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c3ced5;
    height: 34px;
    text-indent: none;
    color: #174267;
}
.menu-sectors-container li a {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #174267;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 0px 7px 7px;
}
.menu-sectors-container li a:active,
.menu-sectors-container li a:hover {
    width: 318px;
    background-image: url(images/hover_bg.png);
    background-position: right -5px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1005;
    color: #fff;
    margin-right: -17px;
    padding:11px 0 13px 10px;
}
.menu-sectors-container li a:hover li {}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like sub-menu li's are floated left when in a mobile type width.  Could the float left on the li's be pushing them in behind some other elements?

Comment: Do you mean left: auto; ?

Comment: The li's with these classes assigned, "menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page", are float:left in the computed-style (Chrome Inspector).  I am wondering if the float:left attribute is messing with the sub-menu li's flow?

Comment: I've tried playing around with the CSS but nothing is changing, still does not show the Child items. The 'Load' Child page actually shows the Child items automatically though!?

Answer (score 0):

On touch devices there is no mouse cursor so hover state does not exist and resulting in not knowing to show the subnav list.
Some devices treat quick tap as hover but AFAIK it's not a standard behaviour.

Simple JavaScript listeners for touch events like "touchstart" should do the trick.

Comment: It looks like the sub-menu is displayed regardless if there is a hover state or not.  It looks like the sub-menu is getting hidden or breaking out of flow in a mobile viewport width.

Comment: Ok that's good to know there is a function to expand the list of Child items on Mobile view. How would I integrate this Touchstart Javascript?

Comment: Lowkase, you're right, it seems as if the Child items (Sub-Menu) is being hidden or something in Mobile view?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue. There were two .sub-menu's under the Mobile section, which I didn't even realise. Editing one and something not happening is the reason why, because the other class was still being applied!